# Enable IPVS Mode in Kube Proxy on a ready Kubernetes Local Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kube-proxy, kubeconfig

I want to enable the Kube-proxy mode to IPVS in the existing cluster. currently, it is running on IPtables. how can I change it to IPVS without affecting the existing workload?

I have already installed all the required modules to enable it. Also, my cluster is installed using kubeadm but, I have not used the configuration file during installation.
what should be the command exactly to enable the IPVS on my cluster.

[documentation1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/pkg/proxy/ipvs)

[documentation2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#config-file)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Edit the configmap

```
kubectl edit configmap kube-proxy -n kube-system
```

change mode from "" to ipvs

```
mode: ipvs
```

Kill any kube-proxy pods

```
kubectl get po -n kube-system
kubectl delete po -n kube-system <pod-name>
```

Verify kube-proxy is started with ipvs proxier

```
kubectl logs [kube-proxy pod] | grep "Using ipvs Proxier"
```

Comment: I got to my pc and couldn't get my kubeadm answer to work.  This one works for me so I deleted the previous answer.

Comment: Did this on loaded production cluster. So far no problems or downtime occurred.