# Why does the ipvs scheduler keep coming back to rr?

Tags: kubernetes, ipvs

I have one k8s-master, one k8s-workernode.

I created 3 pods, 1 deployment, 1 service(`type=ClusterIP`).

And kube-proxy-mode was [modified to ipvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56493651/enable-ipvs-mode-in-kube-proxy-on-a-ready-kubernetes-local-cluster).

Fixed cluster IP from `rr` to `lc`.

```
(ipvsadm -E -t {ClusterIP:Port} -s lc
ipvsadm-save
ipvsamd-Ln)
```

However, if you check it after a few seconds, it returns to `rr`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the mode on the kube proxy command line.

Comment: Hot to set ipvs mode?

kubectl edit configmap kube-proxy -n kube-system

and

mode: ipvs

and also env setting

KUBE_PROXY_MODE=ipvs

Is there anything else to do?

Comment: Did you reboot the kube-proxy pods? Have checked the [prerequisites](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/proxy/ipvs/README.md#prerequisite)?

Comment: You have to pass `–ipvs-scheduler=lc`. Otherwise as you noted kube-proxy uses rr by default.