# What does it means "can't set sysctl net/ipv4/vs/conn_reuse_mode" when set ipvs mode whith k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy, ipvs

When I modify kube-proxy mode from iptales to ipvs, after restart the kube-proxy,
"kubectl logs kube-proxy" return the following error:

server.go:485] unable to create proxier: can't set sysctl net/ipv4/vs/conn_reuse_mode: open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/conn_reuse_mode: no such file or directory

And I confirmcon that I have installed dependent kernel modules by following cmd:

lsmod | grep ip_vs
lsmod | grep conntrack

All are ok,so what should I do with the above error?

Answer (score 0):

What modifications are you exactly introducing to your `kube-proxy` and how ? If you are only setting ipvs mode you can do it in a way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56497675/11714114) and there shouldn't be any problems.

If you're also configuring some additional `sysctls` in the `securityContext` of your `kube-proxy` `Pods`, you may need to consider the following.

Keep in mind that there are so called safe and unsafe sysctls. As you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/#enabling-unsafe-sysctls):

> All  *safe*  sysctls are enabled by default.
>
> All  *unsafe*  sysctls are disabled by default and must be allowed
>   manually by the cluster admin on a per-node basis. Pods with disabled
>   unsafe sysctls will be scheduled, but will fail to launch.
>
> With the warning above in mind, the cluster admin can allow certain 
>   *unsafe*  sysctls for very special situations such as high-performance or real-time application tuning.  *Unsafe*  sysctls are enabled on a
>   node-by-node basis with a flag of the kubelet; for example:
>
> ```
> kubelet --allowed-unsafe-sysctls \   'kernel.msg*,net.core.somaxconn' ...
> ```

Comment: thx for mario‘s answer，finally I find that it need to update the kernel version